# How to check that an ideal of $\Bbb Z[X]$ is not prime?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

Prime ideal of $\Bbb Z[X]$ is $(0)$ or $(f)$  or $(p, f)$

($f\in\Bbb Z[X]$, $f$ is an irreducible element. And $p$ is a prime number)

By the statement above, $(x^3+2,2x^2+3)$ is not a prime ideal.

I don't know how to check this...

I think there is no way to make $(x^3+2,2x^2+3)$ simpler.
(I mean simpler by transforming $(x^2, x+1)$ to $(x+1, 1)$)

Comment: Just a note on terminology: $5\in \Bbb Z[X]$ is irreducible.

Comment: Yes, I know prime element = irreducible element in the situation above.

Comment: My computation shows that $x-21$ belongs to the given ideal. Then consider $x=21$ and find that $\mathbb Z[x]/(x^3+2,2x^2+3)\simeq\mathbb Z/59$ which is an integral domain, so the ideal is prime (maximal).

Comment: @user26857 I noticed $3x-4$ is in this ideal so the answer below(Carry on Smiling's) is incomplete. But I still wonder how did you get $x-21$, and how do you get $\Bbb Z[x]/(x^3+2, 2x^2+3) \cong \Bbb Z/59$. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$3x-4 = x(2x^2+3) - 2(x^3+2)$$

$$-8x-9 = 2x(3x-4) - 3(2x^2+3)$$

$$x-21 = 3(3x-4) + (-8x-9)$$

So we have: $$(x^3 + 2, 2x^2 + 3) = (x^3 + 2, 2x^2 + 3, x-21)$$ $$= (21^3 + 2, 2\cdot 21^2 + 3, x-21) = (9263,885,x-21)$$

But $\gcd(9263,885)=59$, so $(x^3 + 2, 2x^2 + 3) = (59,x-21)$.  From here it is easy to see that the quotient is $\mathbb{Z}/59$. (Or, you can take $p=59$ and $f=x-21$, and use the first sentence of the question!)